# Creating a matrix so its Euclidean norm (p=2) is < 1

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have to convert $Ax=b$ to the form $x=Bx+b$, so $\|B\|_2 < 1$.
I'm having serious trouble with picking/creating the matrix $B$ and it's making me nuts. Can someone give me an example or a hint?

The matrix $A \ (m=n=70)$ I'm working with is:

\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & ... & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & ... & 0 \\
... & ... & ... & ...& ...& \\
0 & ... & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & ... & 0 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

the matrix b is:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
... \\
0 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}

x is:

\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
... \\
x_{70} 
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: By $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{2}$, do you mean $\Vert B \Vert_{2}^{2} = \rho(B^{\top}B)$ ?

Comment: If $Ax=b$ should be equivalent to $x=Bx+b$ for all $x$, then $A=I-B$ so $B=I-A$. Such a $B$ does not satisfy $\|B\|_2<1$. In fact, $\|B\|_2=1+2\cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}$.

Comment: You can, however, transform $Ax=b$ to $Mx=Nx+b$, that is, $x=Bx+c$, where $A=M-N$, $B=M^{-1}N$ and $c=M^{-1}b$ in the spirit of classical iterations such as Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel methods. If $A=D-E$, where $D$ is the diagonal part of $A$, $M=D$ leads to the Jacobi method. In this simple example, $B=D^{-1}E=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tridiag}(-1,0,-1)$, for which $\|B\|_2=\cos\frac{\pi}{n+1}<1$.

Comment: $B=\frac{1}{2}tridiag(-1,0,-1)$ would be correct, if $b=0$. But since $b_{1,1}=1$, then using this $B$, $x=Bx+b$ would be incorrect (I just tried using it for classical iteration).